# Add Custom Thumbnails on Custom Post Types in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I’ve set up a custom post type and I want the featured image to be cropped an resized for these types of post.

This code in functions.php correctly sizes and crops the featured images:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_image_size( 'team_thumb', 719, 719, true);
```

And something like this makes it *appear* in the post:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('team_thumb'); ?>
```

But, the featured image that gets pulled from the page on the Essential Grid, or when sharing on social is still the full sized image.

What do I need to put in my custom post template (or elsewhere in the theme) to make the featured image associated with these custom posts the cropped/resized version?

Comment: What is the "essential grid"? I Presume its some custom theme/plugin? What is the code that this "essential grid" is using to display the image? Is *it* using the correct image size? We can't tell whats going on in custom code if you don't show us the relevant parts, or explain exactly what the issue is.

Comment: make sure you are editing the correct template, fallen into this trap several times, your code above is correct and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress creates thumbnails when the file is uploaded. If you already uploaded images before adding "add_image_size" you must regenerate the thumbnail.

To do so you must use a plugin like "Force regenerate thumbnail" : https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: That's not the issue. The thumbnails are generating correctly but I need to know how to use that thumbnail as a featured image on these custom post types.